# How to convert date patterns using regex python

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I want to convert date from these two formats 21/01/2022 and 21-Jan-22 into 21 Jan 2022. Format needed day(2 int) month(3 string) year(4 int). Thanks

```py
import pandas as pd

data_dict = {
            'date': ['I paid USD 10,000.00 on 21/01/2022 for car service',
                     'I paid USD 10,000.00 on 21-Jan-22 for car service'
                    ]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```

Comment: so you want which date? does the real string have both or only one?

Comment: not both types at once. but could be one in two types

Comment: OK, I updated your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex and `pandas.to_datetime`:

```
regex = r'(\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}|\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2})'
df['new'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.extract(regex, expand=False),
                            dayfirst=True)
               .dt.strftime('%d %b %y')
             )
```

output:

```
                                                date        new
0  I paid USD 10,000.00 on 21/01/2022 for car ser...  21 Jan 22
1  I paid USD 10,000.00 on 21-Jan-22 for car service  21 Jan 22
```